# how to create periodic request using work manager with chained workers

Tags: android, android-workmanager

how to create periodic request  using work manager with chained workers.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest validateEncryptionKey = new 
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            EncryptionKeyWorker.class,
            repeaptInterval,
            TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setInputData(
                    EncryptionKeyWorker.createInputData(
                            false,
                            1,
                            encryptionPublicKeyVersion))
            .build();

    PeriodicWorkRequest uploadImage = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            UploadImageWorker.class,
            repeaptInterval,
            TimeUnit.HOURS).build();
```

I want to chain theses two periodic requests together

Answer (score 1):

Why not schedule a periodic worker (TriggerWorker.kt) whose job is just to trigger the unique jobs, that will actually execute as non-periodic.

This way you can use `.beginWith(compressWorker, renameWorker, uploadWorker)` as suggested in some answers.

Answer (score 0):

From PeriodicWorkRequest [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest)

> Periodic work cannot be part of a chain or graph of work.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to start them together, then just put them in one call and manager runs all of those tasks in parallel

```
.beginWith(workA, workB, workC)
```

but if you would like chain them like one start after another - it is impossible for `PeriodicWorkRequest`

Comment: I want to chain them together, is it possible to create a PeriodicWorkRequest that simply runs a chain of multiple OneTimeRequests sequentially.